# how to deploy elasticsearch in predix?

Tags: elasticsearch, cloud-foundry, predix

I am trying to deploy elasticsearch in predix, I tried to push the downloaded elasticsearch folder into predix with the following manifest.

```
---
applications:
- name: elastic-search-test3
  buildpack: java_buildpack
  # path: target/elstic-search-test-1.0.0.jar
  command: elasticsearch-5.2.2/bin/elasticsearch -f
  #timeout : 180
```

am getting error like port should not be hard coded, should need to use $PORT.

then I tried to set to set the port and  host in elasticsearch config as follows

```
http.port: ${VCAP_APP_PORT}
network.host: ${VCAP_APP_HOST}
```

but no luck.

Can someone point to solution to deploy elasticsearch on predix?

Comment: Can you show the full error you get?

Comment: Error restarting application: Start app timeout; Application must be listening on the right port. Instead of hard coding the port, use the $PORT environment variable

Answer (score 0):

You should use CF_INSTANCE_* variables instead of depreciated VCAP_APP_* DEA ones on newer CF versions.

More on https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, still I am getting the same error

Comment: CF_TRACE=true && cf push ?

config/jvm.options?

config/elasticsearch.yml?